# Открытие n-го количества браузеров

Tags: c#, браузер

Собственно из картинки все понятно. Ребят помогите открыть несколько браузеров по нажатию кнопки. Для манипуляций использую библиотеку Selenium. Вот например код открытия 1 браузера.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWebDriver Browser = new ChromeDriver();
        Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
```

А вот так можно открыть 2:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWebDriver Browser = new ChromeDriver();
        Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        IWebDriver Browser2 = new ChromeDriver();
        Browser2.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
```

Нужно либо через массив либо через цикл или еще как то добавить количество открываний, но в голову ничего не приходит.

[image: Открыть несколько браузеров]

Answer (score 1):

Сам додумался=)Вот код:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count();
    }

    public void Count() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
        {
            IWebDriver br = null;
            Open(br);
        }
    }

    public void Open (IWebDriver browser) {

        browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
```

Comment: 1)Лучше называйте методы более понятными словами.
2) Не понятно зачем создавать IWebDriver br в цикле. Можно вынести.
3) А вообще, зачем вы передаете null в качестве параметра? Его можно было создать в методе Open.